# Is there a way i can get applicationContext in cordova using javascript?

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

I use angular build to generate a cordova android application. I need to get applicationContext in order for me to integrate with third party. Is there a way i can get using JavaScript?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use JS at the wrong place. I don't see how getting the applicationContext in JS could be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to get something similar to from native android project:

```
public class MyApp extends android.app.Application {
    private static MyApp instance;
    public MyApp() {
        instance = this;
    }
    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Is that the context you need? If yes, then no - you cant get and access it directly. But, you can write a plugin, that will pass required parameters from and to it that will manipulate the context in the native code.